# Is .NET 3.5 SP1 Required on the server to use Dynamic Data?

Tags: asp.net, deployment, dynamic-data

Is .NET 3.5 SP1 Required on the server to use Dynamic Data?

It looks like it generates a lot of code and therefore wouldn't require anything special on the server side. I ask because I would like to use it but the shared hosting provider my client is using only have 3.5 installed and not 3.5 SP1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, SP1 is required.

There are several bits of SP1 that Dynamic Data uses, notably the ASP.NET routing extensions and the new data annotation classes in System.ComponentModel.